# Change Alpha Vantage API from Symbol to WKN

Tags: c#, stock, alpha-vantage

How can I change this API call to search for the WKN instead of the symbol or is there any workaround?

```
string url = $"https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=
{symbol}&apikey=API-Key";
```

I can't find any Information on the docs or some elsewhere on the web.                    ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎